# Meaning of symbol unclear (term ^ underlined n)

Tags: calculus

Can you help to explain what the underline means? Does it have a name?

${(a +b)}^{\underline{n}}$

Edit:
According to Wikipedia (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer-Symbol), its way to describe the raising fractorials as

$ x^{\overline{n}}=\frac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!} $

and the falling fractorials as

$ x^{\underline{n}}=\frac{x!}{(x-n)!} $

Comment: [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol#Alternate_notations), in this case "falling factorial".

Comment: Thank you! Never heard the name before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the ["falling factorial" or sometimes "Pochammer symbol"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol#Alternate_notations).